# How create Web Services on AS400 JDE and consume them in Netbeans Java

Tags: java, web-services, stored-procedures, netbeans, jde

My problem is that I don't know how access the data from my java application. I am using netbeans 6.9.1 and I created already a connection with AS400 using jdbc:as400://DBase...
I tried to create Stored Procedures or create Web Services to consume them from my java application, but I couldn't. Also, I tried to create Entities Classes from Database but AS400 database has not primary keys. Any idea how I can use this database in my java application? Thank a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @hetch those something steps for create WEB SERVICES on AS/400 databases and WSDL file exposed. :)

1. Create a DataSource

   ```
   public DataSource getDataSource(String bd) throws Exception {
        DataSource ds = null;
        try {
           if(bd.trim().equals("as400")) {
                ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/your_name_jndi");
           }
           return ds;
        } catch(NamingException n) {
               throw new Exception("Err getDataSource NamingException - " + n.getMessage());
        }
   }
   ```
2. Create your Bean's
3. Create a Connection to database 
   **UPDATE**
   --This class you can to connect to databases whatever, i.e. (ORACLE, MYSQL, SQL-SERVER, etc, etc).--

   ```
   public class DataBases {
        public static Connection con = null;
        static public ServiceLocator locator;

        public DataBases() throws Exception {
               super();
        }

        public Connection getConexionAS400() {
              try {
                 con = locator.getDataSource("AS/400").getConnection();
                 System.out.println("CONECCTED AS/400 DB. " + con);
              } catch(Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return con;
        }
   }


    public final class ServiceLocator {
         private static ServiceLocator pcf;
         private static InitialContext ic;

         /**.
          * Context initialize.
          * @throws Exception
          */
          private ServiceLocator() throws Exception {
                try {
                   ic = new InitialContext();
                } catch (NamingException n) {
                       throw new Exception(
                       "Err InitialContext (ServiceLocator) NamingException - "
                       + n.getMessage());
                }
           }

           /**.
            * Generate instance servicelocator
            * @return service locator
            * @throws Exception
            */
            public static ServiceLocator getInstance() throws Exception {
                 if(pcf == null) {
                       synchronized (ServiceLocator.class) {           
                               pcf = new ServiceLocator();              
                       }
                 }
                 return pcf;
            }

            /**.
             *
             * @param dsName Nombre del jdbc
             * @return DataSource
             * @throws Exception
             */
             public DataSource getDataSource(String bd) throws Exception {
                   DataSource ds = null;
                   try {   
                   if(bd.trim().equals("as400")) {
                            ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/tiempoaire1");
                       }
                       return ds;
                    } catch(NamingException n) {
                           throw new Exception(
                           "Err getDataSource (ServiceLocator) NamingException - "
                           + n.getMessage());
                    }
             }
     }
   ```
4. Create classes to CRUD to database, in this step you will have know ID tables on CRUD works.

That's it !!!

**I hope help you.** :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. One question, when you said in point 3 "Create a connection database" you means that one I have already created? Do you have an example code? or direct me a link so I can take a look of some examples? Than you again!!!

Comment: Hi, I been very busy at work. Using your code today having a error on line "con = locator.getDataSource("AS/400").getConnection();". The "AS/400" is suppose to be the DB url? In that line I am getting a nullPoitException. Do you have an example how use this code? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, in the point 4, I still can't figured out how create the entities from database. How I will create the ID for each table? I have to do it manually?